# What is big O of java priorityQueue poll() method

Tags: java, big-o

I checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue
it said Naive implementations is o(n).

If I use binary search, it will be log(n). But I am not sure if it  is used in Java.
And how do I use binary search on a priorityQueue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just asking about the implementation of Java's `poll`? There's [no substitute](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html) for [reading the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#line-531). Of course, the [standard documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) already answers this particular question.

Comment: PriorityQueues are normally using Heap-based implementations for good reasons. So Java does.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [PriorityQueue Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> Implementation note: this implementation provides **O(log(n))** time for
>   the enqueing and dequeing methods (`offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and
>   `add`); linear time for the `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)`
>   methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods (`peek`,
>   `element`, and `size`).

Priority queues are typically implemented using a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). If implemented as a sorted array, the head can be looked up and removed in O(1) since it is always the last element*, but inserting new elements is O(n) since the insertion point needs to be found (which could be done in O(log(n)) using a binary search) and then all the later elements need to be shifted to make room, which is O(n).

<sup>* Assuming the head is the smallest element and the array is sorted in descending order.</sup>